# How enable RDP on Windows 10 bypassing confirmation dialog?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

There some way to enable RDP programatically on Windows 10 bypassing [confirmation dialog](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/remote_desktop_7.png)?

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DuNamM2nts) approach not do nothing, except seems enable only [this](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/remote_desktop_1.png) setting:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

---

**Editon:**

I also tested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64780110/enabling-rdp-by-changing-registry-setting-only-works-if-rdp-has-been-enabled-sev) suggestion, but not worked.

- Windows 10 2004 - 1941

Comment: What RDP client are you using exactly?

Comment: You need to also allow it through the firewall if you haven't already -  

netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote desktop" new enable=yes

Comment: @Ramhound, RDP Client default of Windows.

Comment: Group Policy could probably do this.